# Securing and Attaching Home Electrical Mast

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

I was recently notified by my electrical company that the electrical mast routing electricity from overhead wires into my house was in not in compliance for permanent service.

The problem is that "the service mast conduit must have 2 points of attachment: 2 Kindorf brackets, or 2 U-bolts, or 1 U-bolt and a guy kit, or 1 Kindorf  and a guy kit". I believe this refers to the pipe above the meter, which currently is not attached to the home. They specifically won't allow "pipe straps".

Which of these options (U-bolt, Kindorf, or Guy Kit) is the most cost effective and easy to install? What's the basic instructions for installation? The utility's approved diagram is below.

[image: electrical mast]

[image: Utitlity]

Comment: the U-Bolt is the most cost effective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how well you know the area under the siding, you may find that a Kindorf bracket pair will be the easiest to install. A U-bolt requires access to the rear to secure the nuts, which seems unlikely with your siding. It seems unlikely with any house covering system.

A Kindorf bracket is rather common in the electrical field, although until now, I was not aware that I knew the product.

You would have to be able to secure a slotted rail across the axis of the pipe currently in place, perhaps wedged between the siding and the pipe. You would need to locate studs into which the rail would be fastened.

The Kindorf brackets are similar to the prohibited pipe straps but more strongly constructed.

[image: Kindorf bracket]

Even though the image above shows an L-bracket rail mount, the rails are available for surface mounting.

I think the most challenging part of this correction is to find the studs inside the wall.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe strap is perforated metal strip, usually with holes and comes in a roll. A Kindorf strap, Unistrut or B-Line, all brand names, are made specific for each size and type of conduit or pipe. I would find 2 studs, predrill them, you wouldn’t want to just run a lag screw in each to attach the “rail”directly to the wall using washers of course, and then use the proper size and brand straps for the job. The rail and strap are to be no more than 2’ from the box.